# Somehow possible to get a HMODULE from a HANDLE?

Tags: c++, winapi

How can I get the HMODULE from an open process handle in visual c++ ?
For example: If I have a handle to another Process (created with OpenProcess) and I want to get the HMODULE of the handle ?

Is this just a simple cast?

```
(HMODULE)myHandle;
```

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

You can't just cast, but you can pass it to [`EnumProcessModules`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631(v=vs.85).aspx) to retrieve the list of modules associated with the given process. The first module returned is the primary module for the process, so you can (probably) pass a buffer that can hold just a single `HMODULE`.

Comment: of course this will be not work (or give wrong result) in case 32bit source process (which do query) and 64bit target. but in another case - ok

Comment: @RbMm There's an alternative [`EnumProcessModulesEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682633(v=vs.85).aspx) for selectively retrieving 32 and/or 64 bit modules regardless of the bitness of the calling process.

Comment: no, this is only alternative for 64bit processes. 32bit process can not get `HMODULE` this way. simply because it 32bit value in 32bit process, when it 64bit value for 64bit. simply will be trancate